# Want to remove [apply], [script] like keywords from file

Tags: ant

I am using following code block:

```
<copy tofile="${dir.report}\${file.report.name}.html" file="${dir.report}\${file.report.name}.html">
    <filterchain>
        <tokenfilter>
             <replaceregex pattern="\[(script|apply)\]" replace="" />
        </tokenfilter>
    </filterchain>
</copy>
```

But replaceregex is not working
Can someone help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a simpler solution:

```
<copy tofile="build/input1.html" file="src/input1.html">
  <filterchain>
    <tokenfilter>
      <replacestring from="apply" to=""/>
      <replacestring from="script" to=""/>
    </tokenfilter>
  </filterchain>
</copy>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<copy>` task cannot "self-copy" files. The source file path has to be different than the destination file path.

Luckily, the [`<replaceregexp>` task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html) provides a simpler solution:

```
<replaceregexp file="${dir.report}\${file.report.name}.html" flags="g">
    <regexp pattern="\[(script|apply)\]"/>
    <substitution expression=""/>
</replaceregexp>
```